# print and download image in React MDX blog

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like this :

```js
<ImageGrid>

<myCard title="first image" url="https://test.test" image="https://img1.link" />

<myCard title="second img " url="https://test.test" image="https://img2.link" />

<myCard title="3rd img" url="https://test.test" image="https://img2.link" />

</ImageGrid>
```

If someone can help me to add print image 1 button to print only img1 and button 2 to print img2

thank you

Comment: Where do you want to add them?

Comment: <myCard title="first image" url="https://test.test" image="https://img1.link"  printbutton=... />

Comment: button 1 inside card1 
button 2 inside card2 ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

React components **must** be capitalized. `myCard` should `MyCard`, otherwise, during the transpilation, React will interpret them as HTML elements, breaking your code.

```
<ImageGrid>

<MyCard title="first image" url="https://test.test" image="https://img1.link" />

<MyCard title="second img " url="https://test.test" image="https://img2.link" />

<MyCard title="3rd img" url="https://test.test" image="https://img2.link" />

</ImageGrid>
```